# Make columns with values 1-4 per group

Tags: postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-9.6

I have a postgres 9.6 database containing a table with persons and nationalities that looks like this:

```
  person_id   nationality  
 ----------- ------------- 
          1   American     
          2   British      
          3   Canadian     
          3   Dutch        
          3   Ethiopian    
          3   French       
          3   German
```

I'm making a table for analysis purposes that contains one row per person. I want to add four columns for the first four nationalities per person. This is my expected result:

```
  person_id    nat_a     nat_b     nat_c     nat_d   
 ----------- ---------- ------- ----------- -------- 
          1   American                               
          2   British                                
          3   Canadian   Dutch   Ethiopian   French
```

Person 3's fifth nationality (German) is not visible due to being fifth. Nationalities B through D of person 1 and 2 are `NULL`s.

I'm currently creating this table in the following way:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    person_id,
    nth_value(nationality, 1) OVER w AS nat_a,
    nth_value(nationality, 2) OVER w AS nat_b,
    nth_value(nationality, 3) OVER w AS nat_c,
    nth_value(nationality, 4) OVER w AS nat_d
FROM nationalities
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY nationality ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

This query delivers the result as expected. However, I'm not quite satisfied with its approach. Because `nth_value` is a window function, I need to specify a window and then apply a `DISTINCT` operation. I'd much prefer to use a `GROUP BY` or something similar.

Is there a more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: You want to create a pivot table. But you need to create a criteria that tells the query which element gets into the first, second, ... new column. For example a row number within each group. This can be simply done with a window function. There are some other methods but all of them are less performant. I added an answer with a row_number window function and a classical pivot algorithm. Why do you want to avoid the window function?

Comment: Added a version without window function but it is much much slower

Answer (score 0):

You wrote you want to avoid using a window function. Nevertheless this answer is using the row_number function but do not need a DISTINCT. Maybe this helps.

As written in the comment: You want to create a pivot table. But you need to create a criteria that tells the query which element gets into the first, second, ... new column. For example a row number within each group. This can be simply done with a window function.

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=4950904852d422e33ebafec0b440553e)

```
WITH ordered AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY nationality)
    FROM
        nationalities
)
SELECT
    person_id,
    MAX(nationality) FILTER (WHERE row_number = 1) AS nat_a,
    MAX(nationality) FILTER (WHERE row_number = 2) AS nat_b,
    MAX(nationality) FILTER (WHERE row_number = 3) AS nat_c,
    MAX(nationality) FILTER (WHERE row_number = 4) AS nat_d
FROM
    ordered
GROUP BY person_id
ORDER BY person_id
```

---

Solution without window function:

[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=32f0cce76a6ec34a42129a44147b56be)

```
WITH ordered AS (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            person_id,
            array_agg(nationality ORDER BY nationality) AS a
        FROM
            nationalities
        GROUP BY person_id
    ) s,
    unnest(a) WITH ORDINALITY AS a(nationality, ordinality)
)
SELECT
    person_id,
    MAX(nationality) FILTER (WHERE ordinality = 1) AS nat_a,
    MAX(nationality) FILTER (WHERE ordinality = 2) AS nat_b,
    MAX(nationality) FILTER (WHERE ordinality = 3) AS nat_c,
    MAX(nationality) FILTER (WHERE ordinality = 4) AS nat_d
FROM
    ordered
GROUP BY person_id
ORDER BY person_id
```

This query aggregates all nationalities per id and unnests it with ordinality. That generates a row number also.

But this version is much much slower:
[demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b8e8aeba95f33ba2f984884c9d1d1303) In fact your version seems to be the fastest in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use WINDOW functions, you can make use of Postgres's [LATERAL sub-queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL):

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_id, a.nat_a, b.nat_b, c.nat_c, d.nat_d
FROM nationalities
    -- --------------------------------------------------------
    -- A
    INNER JOIN LATERAL
    (
        SELECT person_id, MIN(nationality)
        FROM nationalities
        GROUP BY person_id
    ) AS a(person, nat_a) ON a.person = nationalities.person_id
    -- --------------------------------------------------------
    -- B
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    (
        SELECT person_id, MIN(nationality)
        FROM nationalities
        WHERE nationality > a.nat_a
        GROUP BY person_id
    ) AS b(person, nat_b) ON b.person = nationalities.person_id
    -- --------------------------------------------------------
    -- C
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    (
        SELECT person_id, MIN(nationality)
        FROM nationalities
        WHERE nationality > b.nat_b
        GROUP BY person_id
    ) AS c(person, nat_c) ON b.person = nationalities.person_id
    -- --------------------------------------------------------
    -- D
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL
    (
        SELECT person_id, MIN(nationality)
        FROM nationalities
        WHERE nationality > c.nat_c
        GROUP BY person_id
    ) AS d(person, nat_d) ON d.person = nationalities.person_id
```

Since you're sorting alphabetically, `nat_a` will always be the `MIN(nationality)`. Successive lateral joins (using a `LEFT JOIN`, for people that only have 1 nationality) can look at the "next MIN" nationality.